# MOBSF android security issue

Tags: java, android

Insecure
Implementation of
SSL. Trusting all the
certificates or
accepting self signed
certificates is a
critical Security
Hole. This
application is
vulnerable to MITM
attacks

Comment: how to fix this

Comment: Use a SSL pinning and secure cipher suite for network request.

Comment: any example how to use this

Comment: Search your project for TrustManager implementations, most likely one of it is not checking the certificate correctly.